# Text alignment to left in Corona

Tags: lua, coronasdk

My problem is that I can't align my text to left. I need to set a position where the text will start and it will go to the left and it wont be centered. Its like in html, you make position and it goes from that position to the right, eventually it makes another line. Maybe a picture example will make you understand better because its hard to describe it.

**How it should look and where it should start all the time if I add more text it should just continue to the right.**

[image: How it should look and where it should start all the time]

**How it looks if I add more text, and that's not how I want it**

[image: How it looks if i add more text, and thats not how i want it]

Here's a bit of the code

```
    text = display.newText("Fair", 0, 0, "HelveticaNeue-Light", 22)
    text.x = halfW - 300
    text.y = halfH + 110
    text.align = "left"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you using the Current Public Release (2014.2100) + ?

Try using `text.anchorX = 0` instead of `text.align = "left"`
So `anchorX = .5` is same as "middle" and `anchorX = 1` is same as "right".